# How to solve TFS Error: TF30063(Unauthorized) when executing MSTest.exe on a hosted agent in VSTS

Tags: tfs, mstest, tfsbuild, azure-devops

When Executing a `TFS` xaml build using `VSTS`, we have a code activity that executes `MSTest.exe` for our unit tests on a build.

This step is failing with the message:

> Cannot connect to Team Foundation Server https
>   ://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/. TF30063: You are not
>   authorized to access https
>   ://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.
>
> **I should note
>   that this is on a hosted build agent in VSTS.** 
>  Build log
>   error screencap: [VSTS Build Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MMuW.png)

We have attempted to give the executing user `Elastic Build (xxxvsts)` all the permissions necessary but it does not seem to make a difference. From what i've read the error seems to happen during the `'/Publish'` part of the `MSTest` call. the unit test executed is a method that has only an

```
 Assert.IsTrue(true);
```

call in it. so it should not fail.

*(I know that vNext is there, but the company I work for does not have the resources for a retooling of our build system)*

Comment: Can you share the code activity you use?